# Video orientation is incorrect on FireFox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video

I have html5 video tags of videos.
On chrome all is good, on firefox the orientation of landscape videos is wrong...

Even tried using video.js, no change.

I read that this is a problem because the videos originated in iOS.

so 2 questions:
1. How can I still overcome this issue. Really there is no solution?
2. (out of curiosity) - how does chrome manage to overcome this?

Example of a URL (scroll down a bit in the chapters to see a vertical video):
http://www.letsfeedme.com/moments/55802f142f2dad3c008b4575-Balsamic-Vinegar-%22Caviar%22

Comment: Are those videos ALWAYS in portrait mode? Or sometimes landscape, sometimes portrait?

Comment: The web page you linked is 67 MB, and the main page of [letsfeedme.com](http://www.letsfeedme.com/) is 131 MB and takes 70 seconds to load. This is before I click play on any of the videos. Just curious - how much is that site costing you on CloudFront? I personally cost you about 2 cents by visiting each of those pages once.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - basically you are right. There are a lot of considerations that make it OK for now (SO comment is not the place to discuss it) - the main "problem" are the videos - I'm doing a play/pause for all to overcome a chrome caching bug. The landing page will change soon...

Comment: If it plays properly in Chrome and VLC (according to other comments) it could be a bug in Firefox. The best solution is to send a bug report to Mozilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). But please, use a test page isolated and easy to load, not the 131 MB link. Mozilla guys are very busy and they will ignore you otherwise.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38228475/1874627).

Comment: I opened the bug back in the day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the problem is with some **iOS specific encoding options, which many NOT-Apple Players can't read**, the easiest solution I can think of is to **trancode and rotate the video**.

Which was already discussed in oh so many posts on the web and here at SO... e.g.:

[Video orientation using video.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415049/video-orientation-using-video-js)

[HTML5 mp4 video with firefox resizing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126230/html5-mp4-video-with-firefox-resizing-video)

[Chrome HTML5 Video Flipping Portrait Sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486870/chrome-html5-video-flipping-portrait-sideways)

http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1508-video-orientation-for-iphone-wrong

Comment: There are no iOS _specific_ encoding options (the [rotation metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33756136/813988) is saved with Android videos as well) and most players do support that metadata (see [list](https://addpipe.com/blog/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/), Firefox does not) but your solution to rotate the video is right if coupled with the removal of that rotation info (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33756136/813988)).

Answer (score 4):

> I read that this is a problem because the videos originated in iOS.

**All videos recorded using mobile devices will contain *rotation metadata* including those from iOS and Android devices.** It can take 4 values: 0 (tilted left), 90 (portrait), 180 and 270:

[image]

> On chrome all is good, on firefox the orientation of landscape videos is wrong...

**Firefox and IE 10 are the only major browsers not supporting the rotation metadata.** Here's Firefox compared with Chrome:

[image]

The latest version, Firefox 42 as of today, still does not support it. IE11 and Edge 12,13 do support it.

List of mobile/desktop players that support the rotation info: https://blog.addpipe.com/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/

> How can I still overcome this issue. Really there is no solution?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33755819/813988) for the solution, basically you need to :

1. **rotate videos using FFmpeg** (so Firefox and other browsers that do not support the rotation metadata show the video properly)
2. **remove the rotation metadata** (so that other players don't rotate the video since it's already been rotated  by FFmepg)

Images courtesy of: https://blog.addpipe.com/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/

Comment: The Mozilla/Firefox bug report for this issue has been getting a lot of activity lately https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228601

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that Chrome is respecting the `width="360"` and `height="640"` attributes of your `<video>` tags, while Firefox is not. If I download one of your videos and play it back in Media Player Classic, again the orientation is incorrect. But just like in web browsers, there are inconsistencies: the same video opened in VLC player plays back with the correct orientation.

I would recommend that, if you can, you re-encode the videos using a (free) program called AVIdemux. I just tried it on one of your videos, and it worked well with minimal effort. As a bonus it shrunk your video down considerably, with only minimal quality loss.

Here are the steps:

1. Download AVIdemux from http://www.fosshub.com/Avidemux.html
2. Install and run AVIdemux
3. Go to File menu and choose Open. Pick the video to re-encode.
4. Go to Video menu and choose Filters
5. Choose Transform > Rotate (double-click) > Rotate by 270 degrees (OK)
6. Click the Preview button to check the output
7. Click the Close button
8. In the main window, under Video Output, choose MPEG4-AVC (x264)
9. Under Output Format, choose MP4 Muxer
10. Click the Save Video icon, and in the resulting window type a filename and click the Save button.

Then you will need to re-upload your video.

Comment: Yeah... The problem I need some sort of automatic solution. The users upload videos all the time...

Comment: Ah, okay. That's unfortunate ;(

Comment: That's because **Media Player Classic does not support the rotation metadata** in video files while VLC does. See the [list of players supporting the rotation metadata](https://addpipe.com/blog/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/) . FFmpeg could be used to automate the rotation process though.

Comment: To hell with you. I followed all your steps and got the error: The video seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not really a viable solution but adding a CSS rule such as

```
video {
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

would at least make the videos play back in the correct orientation in Firefox. Problems with this:

- videos that play back in the correct orientation without the rule will play back in the wrong orientation with the rule
- the video controls also get rotated
- the posters will display in the wrong orientation

I see your site uses video.js. It might be worth looking at https://github.com/xbgmsharp/videojs-rotatezoom ?

Comment: I saw this solution. The rotated controls look ridiculous, not a real solution :( rotatezoom uses the same technique as I see, right?

Comment: No, not a real solution. I tried playing around in Jquery e.g. $("video").removeAttr("controls").css("-moz-transform","rotate(90deg)").attr("controls","controls") but didn't help rotate the controls into the correct position. Aside from modifying the iPhone app to set the correct orientation, I'm out of ideas. Sorry I can't be of more help.