# Why is an HTML video tag displaying the video upside down only in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, video, mozilla

I have a page that displays multiple videos using html video tags. The code looks like the below snippet:

```
<video controls="controls" class="vw" name="Video" src="videos/ACS_Video_2b.mp4"></video>
```

The class is simply a class that dynamically sets the width, height, etc.

The video looks and plays very nicely in all browsers except for Firefox. All of the videos on the website using these tags are upside down in Firefox. I can't seem to find anything online about people having similar problems. In fact, when I go to other websites using identical video tags and video extensions, etc., the video displays perfectly on their site for me in Firefox.

Here is the website with the upside down videos for reference:

http://www.larrykrannich.com/video.html

The videos display upside down locally, on a local server, and hosted on a real server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a firefox problem, I have seen that several people have complained over and over about this problem but all to no avail. it only happens when the video is recorded from mobile, firefox doesn't seem to use the camera details to encoded rotation that came along with the mobile video. for the main time you have to figure out a fix for yourself, you can use css transform to rotate the video tag, but one problem with that is that it will rotate the video control with it.

you can use [videojs](http://videojs.com/), then add the rotate plugin, you can just google it. it will help rotate for video.

you can do something like this

```
 if ( isfirefox ) {

    <video  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="270" height="360" data-setup='{ "plugins": { "zoomoomrotate": { "rotate": "270", "zoom": "1.4" } } }'>
        <source src="video-source" type="video/mp4">         
  </video>

}
```

also, there is a recent issue in chrome update that compress mobile video as well. still looking for a fix for it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with rotation metadata in the video files. The problem can be solved by transcoding and rotating the video. Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920331/video-orientation-is-incorrect-on-firefox)

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, you have recorded the video upside down, without realizing it - which can happen, e.g. when using a smartphone-camera.

There are video-players, that auto-correct for such things, which might be, why you didn't realize the video being upside-down.

There is a free Videoplayer called VLC, which you can correct this with by rotating the video.

Get it here and install it, if you don't already have it:
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Steps:

1. Open video in VLC media player
2. Pause the video, if it's too short to keep running, while you perform the other steps
3. In the upper menu, navigate as follows:

   1. Tools
   2. Video Effects
4. In the window, that just opened go to the Geometry-tab and do the following:

   1. Check the box "Transform"
   2. Select "Rotate by 180 degrees"
5. Your video should now look nice and right side up
6. To save your changes:

   1. In the upper menu click, navigate as follows:

      1. Media
      2. Convert/Save
   2. Choose, where you want to save the file.
7. Upload the rotated video in place of the upside-down one.
8. Now your video should be displayed correctly :)