# video orientation is incorrect in FireFox when the video is from an IOS device

Tags: ios, firefox, video, webrtc, html5-video

I'm currently working on a web app (PWA) that uses WebRTC for real-time communication like videoCall ,videoRoom, ...

So basically I get the live stream and give it to HTML5 Video element as it's source.
the videos are perfectly shown in chrome but when the communication is between an IOS device and FireFox, Firefox rotates the video that has been generated by Iphone and does not show is in correct way...
I've visited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929495/why-is-an-html-video-tag-displaying-the-video-upside-down-only-in-mozilla-firefo)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920331/video-orientation-is-incorrect-on-firefox) understanding this was an issue of FireFox
But now My question is: are there any differences between video streams generated by different devices? and are there any solutions to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a SFU in the middle? If yes, do not negotiate the 3gpp video-orientation header extension